# Certain `import` statements return `undefined` where circular dependencies exist

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, circular-dependency, circular-reference

I recently experienced a bug where some module exports started returning `undefined` where circular references / dependencies exist in my React/Redux/Webpack project.

My question is why did this happen?. I understand that webpack supports circular references and in my application the import worked in some files and not in others (presumably due to the complexity / depth of the dependencies?).

The reason I want to know why is so I can prevent this happening going forwards, obviously I can work to remove the reference issues, but the fact that webpack did eventually manage to process things left me confused why the issue manifested as a timing / race condition type of problem which just took me 10 hours to fix.

I have implemented the `circular-dependency-plugin` module to both display and error when new references might be added but I want to know why webpack seems to handle this...sometimes...and sometimes not.